# "What's past is past" is a good grammar structure?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure about whether “What's past is past” is well-structured or not.
Please help me to find out the structure of it. (I wonder if it has double passive clauses; in other words, is *past* here a verb or an adjective?)

Comment: I've always liked thinking about this phrase because when spoken it can be interpreted as, *'what's past is past'* or *'what's past is passed'* or *'what's passed is past'* or even *'what's passed is passed'* which all mean different things.

Comment: It is what it is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine, as is the extended "What is past is past."

There are no passives.  The main phrase is "Something is past" with the verb *is* followed by an adjective.  That something is the clause *what is past*, again with the verb *is* followed by an adjective.

If you wanted two passives then you could write "What is passed is passed" or "What's passed is passed."  Spoken, these sound the same as what you wrote.

Comment: There are some spelling mistakes in 2nd para, 1st line. Please review them.

Comment: @Mohit: I spotted phase/phrase. Thanks.  If there are others, feel free to edit

Comment: I would have, but it has a minimum 6-character limit. Also, "Thee" in the same line could be fixed up! :)

Comment: @Mohit, right, the proper wording is  “thou art” rather than  “thee are”